# AngularJs dynamic numbering without $index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular.JS and facing an issue.

I have parent,child ,grand child hierarchy in my code.
I have been using $index right now for showing dynamic numbering however i
don't need sequential numbering.

Eg. for parent, numbering needs to set to 1.0 then numbering like(1.A,1.B,1.C...) for child , 1.1 should show for first grand child 
and 1.1.1 for first grand to grand child and so on....
$index is increasing sequentially and  consuming 1.1 for child and showing 1.2 to grandchild instead of 1.1 .I need to setup below numbering pattern in my code.

```
1.0 PARENT1

 1.A FIRST CHILD
  1.1 GRANDCHILD
    1.1.1 GRAND TO GRAND CHILD

 1.B SECOND CHILD
  1.2 GRANDCHILD
    1.2.1 GRAND TO GRAND CHILD

  1.3 GRANDCHILD
    1.3.1 GRAND TO GRAND CHILD
    1.3.2 GRAND TO GRAND CHILD... so on
```

i hope i am able to explain my question properly.Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: You should add the state object and the markup used to produce this. You can probably do this using something like `<div class="child">{{$parent.$index}}.{{['A', 'B', 'C', ...][$index]}}</div>`

Comment: can you add the code related to that ? and try creating a sample demo